# can we undefine/unset a variable in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Team,

I have an environment variable which i would like to undefined/unset during the  compilation of that particular project and then enable that back..

i have tried using.. the below code..

`ifdef ${ENV_VAR_TEST}
    undefine ${ENV_VAR_TEST}
    endif`

but i still see that its get reflected in the compilation environment... are these correct steps to undefined/unset a variable ?..i am i missing some basics here..

Thanks for your time .

Comment: Both **ifdef** and **undefine** should use literal variable name, not **expanded value** of ENV_VAR_TEST, otherwise it will test the value as a variable name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
unexport ENV_VAR_TEST
```

I don't know what the others mean by `undefine`, which doesn't look like valid `make` syntax.

**Edit:** `undefine` exists indeed, but only in GNU make 3.82 and higher.

Comment: @user2719058 unexport has nothing to do with what the question is, maybe it "works" by accident, but is not correct.  undefine is correct. I don't know what _you_ mean by "I don't know what the others mean...", "undefine" is in the manual.

Comment: unexport worked(may be by accident..not sure) however..i did figure out  another way  which is just set "ENV_VAR_TEST="

Comment: "ENV_VAR_TEST=" is not what you asked, it is setting the variable to empty, rather than unsetting it altogether

Comment: Thats correct Mark.. however not able to fine the reason why <code> undefine </code> does not work

Comment: @MarkGaleck: if "undefine" is in the manual, can you please post a link? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Undefine-Directive.html..this the link..

Comment: Ah, found it: new feature in GNU make 3.82. My Debian Squeeze box here has GNU make 3.81.

Comment: @user2719058 why, http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Undefine-Directive

Comment: well, actually, it is 4.0 now.  Long Live our Dear Leader MadScientist

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have a GNU Make 3.81 is that the reason why it gives me the error **missing Operator *** error ?

Comment: @user2189668: yes. Same here.

Comment: probably, upgrade to 4.0, 3.81 is dark ages, 4.0 is not even backwards compatible with that

Comment: @MarkGaleck Regarding correctness, the OP wanted to remove the variable from the environment (of commands run by make), so `unexport` is correct, and not only by accident.

Comment: @user2719058 I am sorry, with all respect, you seem to be confusing the shell export with GNU Make un/export.  There is nothing in the manual that says, that GNU Make unexport, reverses the shell export.  The manual specifically states that GNU Make unexport, is for use in recursive GNU Make invocations.  Perhaps, GNU Make unexport, works in such a way, that when used for a shell environment variable, it is not then available to a recipe used in non-recursive make invocation, but if that is so, it is at best, undocumented.

Comment: ok..i did a quick test using unexport..for a sample script like 

bash-4.1$ make -f sam.mk
echo "0"
0
bash-4.1$ more sam.mk
unexport var_test

ifdef var_test
    yes="1"
endif

ifdef var_test
    yes="0"
endif

all:
 echo $(yes)
bash-4.1$

Comment: @MarkGaleck Well, the manual for GNU make on my system says "To pass down, or "export", a variable, 'make' adds the variable and
its value to the environment for running each command." (Section 5.7.2, "Communicating Variables to a Sub-'make'" That sounds pretty clear to me.

Comment: @user2719058 yes "to Sub-make" that means, recursive Make invocation

Comment: @MarkGaleck. Yeah. And "each command" means all commands, not only sub-makes, right.

Comment: @user2719058 no, clearly, this comment is in the section on "communicating to sub-make", and everything in this section, is applicable to that only by default.  If you disagree with that, then fine, let's disagree, I see no point in further arguing.

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax is

```
undefine ENV_VAR_TEST
```

Comment: and, there is no need for any ifdef/endif

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the NAME of the variable to undefine.  Make will expand the argument to undefine so if the variable `ENV_VAR_TEST` is set to the value `foo`, then `undefine ${ENV_VAR_TEST}` runs `undefine foo`.

You want to use `undefine ENV_VAR_TEST`.

Comment: i did try just doing an <code> ifdef ENV_VAR_TEST undefine ENV_VAR_TEST endif </code>..I send up with <code>Makefile:71: *** missing separator.  Stop. </code>

Comment: Oh woops, unexport.  Sorry I didn't even notice that misspelling!